# Div overlaps div (HTML/CSS)?

Tags: html, css

I'm still learning html and css, trying to figure out how everything works, without any coding experience. Please pardon me if I ask a stupid or totally redundant thing.

Basically, I have 3 divs that I'm working on. 2 divs at the very top of the page, both for logos. One on the top left, one on the top right.
My third div, for a navigation bar, does not go below them, but instead overlaps them.

Should I just use `<br>` a whole lot to deal with it?

Images referenced are local. Please refer to http://ddlgaming.com/giga/ for a live version.

Thank you in advance!

My code is as follows (please ignore all the colours, they help me see better):

CSS and HTML:

```css
.clearfix {
   clear: both;
   }

body
   {
   background-color: rgb(21,14,43);
   background-image: url("../images/backgroundimage.jpg");
   background-size: cover;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-attachment: fixed;
   min-height: 100%;
   background-position: center center;
   overflow: hidden;
   }
 
#gigalogomainbox
   {
   float: left;
   width: 30vw;
   height: 10vw;
   overflow: hidden;
   transform: skewX(20deg);
   margin: 0 0 0 -4vw;
   }
   
#gigalogobox
   {
   margin: 0 3vw 0 2vw;
   padding: 0 0 0 2vw;
   width: 100%;
   height: 8vw;
   }
 
#gigalogo
   {
   width: 80%;
   margin: 3vw 2vw 0 0;
   height: 7vw;
   }
   
#steamlogomainbox
   {
   width: 15vw;
   height: 10vw;
   float: right;
   margin: 0 -4vw 0 0;
   background-color: white; /*000c21*/
   transform: skewX(-20deg);
   overflow: hidden;
   }
     
#steamlogobox
   {
   margin: 0 -2vw 0 3vw;
   padding: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 20%;
   }
#steamlogo
   {
   padding: 0 0 0 2vw;
   margin: 3vw 0vw 0 0;
   transform: skewX(20deg);
   height: 7vw;
   }

#placeholderbartop
   {
   float: left;
   width: 60%;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   height: 10vw;
   }
   

#navbarbox   
   {
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   height: 5vw;
   margin: 0vw;
   background-color: white;
   }
#navbar, #navbar ul
   {
   width: 100%;
   height: 5vw;
   margin: 0;
   background-color: green;
   }
   
#navbar li
   {
   color: white;
   list-style: none;
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 1vw;
   color: red;
   font-size: 30px;
   }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="css/mainframe.css" type="text/css" rel=stylesheet>
<script src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>

<body>


<!--Giga logo, top left--!>
<div id="gigalogomainbox" class="clearfix">
 <div id="gigalogobox">
  <img id="gigalogo"  src="images/gigalogo.png">
 </div>
 <div class="clearfix">
 </div>
</div>

<!--Steam logo, top right--!>
<div id="steamlogomainbox">
 <div id="steamlogobox">
  <img id="steamlogo" src="images/steamlogo.png">
 </div>
 <div class="clearfix">
 </div>
</div>

<!--navigation barrrrrr--!>
<div id="navbarbox">
 <ul id="navbar">
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>Servers</li>
  <li>Community</li>
  <li>Store</li>
  <li>Download</li>
  <li>Contact</li>
 </ul>
</div>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: First of all, your HTML is broken. Comments should be `<!-- Comment -->`. Fix it. Next, your second question about `br`. Using `br` for fixing visual issues isn't good.

Comment: We don't do "SOLVED" in the title here. If you, or someone else, has answered your question, you can mark it as accepted to let others know.

Comment: sorry i didn't know :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because floated elements need to be "cleared" for block elements to display below them, otherwise the inline content in the block elements will wrap around the floated elements. You have a `.clearfix` class in your CSS that you can use. You can apply that to `#navbarbox` or you can wrap your logos in a new element and apply the `.clearfix` class to that element.

btw your html comment syntax is wrong. Should be `<!-- comment -->`, not `<!-- comment --!>`

```css
.clearfix {
   clear: both;
   }

body
   {
   background-color: rgb(21,14,43);
   background-image: url("../images/backgroundimage.jpg");
   background-size: cover;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-attachment: fixed;
   min-height: 100%;
   background-position: center center;
   overflow: hidden;
   }
 
#gigalogomainbox
   {
   float: left;
   width: 30vw;
   height: 10vw;
   overflow: hidden;
   transform: skewX(20deg);
   margin: 0 0 0 -4vw;
   }
   
#gigalogobox
   {
   margin: 0 3vw 0 2vw;
   padding: 0 0 0 2vw;
   width: 100%;
   height: 8vw;
   }
 
#gigalogo
   {
   width: 80%;
   margin: 3vw 2vw 0 0;
   height: 7vw;
   }
   
#steamlogomainbox
   {
   width: 15vw;
   height: 10vw;
   float: right;
   margin: 0 -4vw 0 0;
   background-color: white; /*000c21*/
   transform: skewX(-20deg);
   overflow: hidden;
   }
     
#steamlogobox
   {
   margin: 0 -2vw 0 3vw;
   padding: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 20%;
   }
#steamlogo
   {
   padding: 0 0 0 2vw;
   margin: 3vw 0vw 0 0;
   transform: skewX(20deg);
   height: 7vw;
   }

#placeholderbartop
   {
   float: left;
   width: 60%;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   height: 10vw;
   }
   

#navbarbox   
   {
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   height: 5vw;
   margin: 0vw;
   background-color: white;
   }
#navbar, #navbar ul
   {
   width: 100%;
   height: 5vw;
   margin: 0;
   background-color: green;
   }
   
#navbar li
   {
   color: white;
   list-style: none;
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 1vw;
   color: red;
   font-size: 30px;
   }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="css/mainframe.css" type="text/css" rel=stylesheet>
<script src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>

<body>


<!--Giga logo, top left-->
<div id="gigalogomainbox" class="clearfix">
 <div id="gigalogobox">
  <img id="gigalogo"  src="images/gigalogo.png">
 </div>
 <div class="clearfix">
 </div>
</div>

<!--Steam logo, top right-->
<div id="steamlogomainbox">
 <div id="steamlogobox">
  <img id="steamlogo" src="images/steamlogo.png">
 </div>
 <div class="clearfix">
 </div>
</div>

<!--navigation barrrrrr-->
<div id="navbarbox" class="clearfix">
 <ul id="navbar">
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>Servers</li>
  <li>Community</li>
  <li>Store</li>
  <li>Download</li>
  <li>Contact</li>
 </ul>
</div>

</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `clear: both` or just add you `clearfix` class toyour `navbarbox`

```css
.clearfix {
   clear: both;
   }

body
   {
   background-color: rgb(21,14,43);
   background-image: url("../images/backgroundimage.jpg");
   background-size: cover;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-attachment: fixed;
   min-height: 100%;
   background-position: center center;
   overflow: hidden;
   }
 
#gigalogomainbox
   {
   float: left;
   width: 30vw;
   height: 10vw;
   overflow: hidden;
   transform: skewX(20deg);
   margin: 0 0 0 -4vw;
   }
   
#gigalogobox
   {
   margin: 0 3vw 0 2vw;
   padding: 0 0 0 2vw;
   width: 100%;
   height: 8vw;
   }
 
#gigalogo
   {
   width: 80%;
   margin: 3vw 2vw 0 0;
   height: 7vw;
   }
   
#steamlogomainbox
   {
   width: 15vw;
   height: 10vw;
   float: right;
   margin: 0 -4vw 0 0;
   background-color: white; /*000c21*/
   transform: skewX(-20deg);
   overflow: hidden;
   }
     
#steamlogobox
   {
   margin: 0 -2vw 0 3vw;
   padding: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 20%;
   }
#steamlogo
   {
   padding: 0 0 0 2vw;
   margin: 3vw 0vw 0 0;
   transform: skewX(20deg);
   height: 7vw;
   }

#placeholderbartop
   {
   float: left;
   width: 60%;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   height: 10vw;
   }
   

#navbarbox   
   {
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   height: 5vw;
   margin: 0vw;
   background-color: white;
      clear: both; /*add this*/
   }
#navbar, #navbar ul
   {
   width: 100%;
   height: 5vw;
   margin: 0;
   background-color: green;
   }
   
#navbar li
   {
   color: white;
   list-style: none;
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 1vw;
   color: red;
   font-size: 30px;
   }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="css/mainframe.css" type="text/css" rel=stylesheet>
<script src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>

<body>


<!--Giga logo, top left-->
<div id="gigalogomainbox" class="clearfix">
 <div id="gigalogobox">
  <img id="gigalogo"  src="images/gigalogo.png">
 </div>
 <div class="clearfix">
 </div>
</div>

<!--Steam logo, top right-->
<div id="steamlogomainbox">
 <div id="steamlogobox">
  <img id="steamlogo" src="images/steamlogo.png">
 </div>
 <div class="clearfix">
 </div>
</div>

<!--navigation barrrrrr-->
<div id="navbarbox">
 <ul id="navbar clearfix"><!--or do this-->
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>Servers</li>
  <li>Community</li>
  <li>Store</li>
  <li>Download</li>
  <li>Contact</li>
 </ul>
</div>

</body>


</html>
```